# Isomorphism of Witt groups

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, determinant

This is excerpt from W. Scharlau: *Quadratic and Hermitian Forms,*
[page 36](https://books.google.com/books?id=c27pCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA36).

> A second invariant is the *determinant*.
>   Since $\det(\phi \perp \psi) = \det(\phi) \det(\psi)$ we get by $1.1$ a group homomorphism
>   $$
>   \det \colon \hat{W}(K) \to K^\bullet/K^{\bullet 2}.
> $$
>   We will see in the next section that over finite fields, for example, dimension and determinant are sufficient to classify quadratic spaces.
>   This can be expressed as follows:
>   there is a group isomorphism
>   $$
>          (\dim, \det)
>   \colon \hat{W}(K)
>   \to    \mathbb{Z} \times K^\bullet / K^{\bullet 2}.
> $$
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nIPE.png).)

I know that there is a homomorphic map $\dim \colon  \widehat W(K) \to \mathbb{Z}$. It is the same as the construction of integers from the natural number and $0$. Also there is homomorphic  map from $\det \colon \widehat W(K) \to K^\bullet/K^{\bullet 2}$. Also how one can show homomorphism by using $(\dim,\det)$ map. I think homomorphism is true since the direct product of homomorphism is a homomorphism. But how to write it explicitly? If we know it is homomorphism then we have to show for $(0,0)$ element dimension and $\det$ is $0$ to show kernel is trivial. How to show that?

Comment: what book is this?

Comment: W. Scharlau: Quadratic and Hermitian Forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any quadratic form, there exists a diagonal representation, let's call these representations $D=\langle d_1,\ldots,d_n\rangle$ where $\dim(D)=n.$ Crucially, we may always choose $d_j\in K^\ast/{K^\ast}^2.$ This defines a homomorphism,

$$\dim : \widehat{W}(K)\longrightarrow \Bbb{Z}$$
by
$$\dim(D)\mapsto \text{length}(D).$$
This is certainly a homomorphism, since orthogonal sums of quadratic forms obey the following additive law
$$\underbrace{\langle a_1,\ldots,a_k\rangle}_{\dim = k}\perp\underbrace{ \langle b_1,\ldots,b_\ell\rangle}_{\dim =\ell}\cong\underbrace{ \langle a_1,\ldots,a_k,b_1,\ldots,b_\ell\rangle}_{\dim = k +\ell}.$$

Similarly $$\det(\langle d_1,\ldots,d_n\rangle)=\prod_{j=1}^n d_j\in K^\ast/{K^\ast}^2$$

So the map $$(\dim,\det)(D)=(\dim(D),\det(D))=\left(\text{length}(D),\prod_{j=1}^n d_j\right)$$
is the explicit homomorphism.

Comment: Why it is isomorphic?

Comment: How to show kernel is trivial?

Comment: $\dim(D)=0\iff D$ is the empty quadratic form, and $\det(D)=0$ is more accurately saying that the product of the terms is equal to $1\in K^\ast/{K^\ast}^2.$

Comment: How to show that the map (det,dim) is isomorphic to that group

Comment: please have a look at it

Comment: @Ninjahatori Isn't the fact that $(\dim,\det)$ is a bijection (and thus isomorphism) precisely precisely [Theorem 3.8](https://books.google.com/books?id=c27pCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA39) from the book you're studying (Scharlau)?